# text editor enable me to code direct on host like text editor for bluehost

Tags: javascript, html, php

I want to code direct online. Is there a text editor allow me to code online direct to host without upload code to host? I don't want to code on localhost then upload it. I want to code online.

can anyone recommend a software for me do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have SSH access to the host, then Vim (https://www.vim.org/) is worth considering.

Comment: Or `joe` or `nano` or any of the other console text editors.  While `vi` or `vim` is very powerful, there is a slight learning curve.  Check your favorite linux distribution for the `vimtutor` command